# How do I route a workflow to approvers based on criteria from a document?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have been asked to build a workflow using Sharepoint designer  in which a user will select a budget source and amount from a document, and then the approval task would need to  be sent to multiple approvers based on the selection.

I have very little experience  and want to learn so I am looking for some guidance.

As an example if the user chooses manufacturing as the budget source, and the requested budget is 51 k it would need to go to all the approvers listed on the matrix. (see screen shot)

I guess I am looking for some suggestions/ advice  on how to implement this first step and what structure needs to be in place.  Any advise or direction would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of different ways you can model this. As you start automating this you will probably find it get's more complicated :)

Since you are new - I would start simple first:

1. Document library, need columns that capture the section and the
   amount.
2. In the workflow I start with a single branch for Manufacturing.

So in the workflow:

1. Check that it's a manufacturing request first. End if not else continue.
2. Check if value if greater than $1k - if not end, if yes continue.
3. Configure Approval tasks for the first group
4. If approved you will check for the next value amount, if rejected - you can message the initiator and end workflow.

You will continue this down thru your workflow until you get all approvers.  I would work thru one section at a time and test each step (vs. trying to get the logic for the entire thing in one go).

This initial workflow will require the use of SharePoint tasks - and your automatic approval links in email won't work (they will need to open the task and approve it).

Other things you will want to consider is using "*lookup*" lists.  Create lists that drive the workflow, for example a role list might have the Functional area, Role, Contact, and Dollar amount for approvals and in the workflow you will query this list and return these values.  This way as positions change you don't have to edit the workflow directly.  But my advise is start as simple as you can at first and validate the process, and the automation steps as you go.  "*SharePoint Designer*" is an entry to middle level workflow tool.

If you will be doing more of these - and they start to get complicated in their requirements, you may want to look at *Nintex* or *K2*.  Nintex supports a feature called "*Lazy approval*" that accepts approvals via email messages (and probably easier to use for a beginner as far as getting more advanced functionality from the tool).

There are many Designer tutorials available that will help you find your way around the tool [here](https://www.bing.com/search?q=SharePOint%20designer%202013%20workflows%20getting%20started&pc=MOZI&form=MOZSBR).